# How to reference an ndb entity when I have the ID attribute

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I currently have the ID attribute for an ndb entity. I can't seem to get the entity. I only know how to get the entity with the key name. This is what i have to try and reference it:

```
story = ndb.Key(Place, data['entryKey']).get()
```

Comment: Do you mean an id attribute of the key ? or a property of the entity called id ? If you mean an id in the context of the key it is just the system generated id, where as the key name is a value you provide but both use the same calling convetion - get_by_id.  If you mean a property of an entity called id then you have to perform a query.

Answer (score 2):

There is a get_by_id method

> get_by_id(id, parent=None, app=None, namespace=None, **ctx_options)
>
> Returns an entity by ID. This is really just a shorthand for Key(cls,
> id).get().

But it seems it is shorthand for what you are currently doing anyway.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/modelclass#Model_get_by_id